# Magebto 2 Compilation error: interceptor file doesn't exists due to amasty extensions

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

We have installed the amasty import orders extension manually in app/code and after deleted the extensions and run the magento commands in production mode but getting the below error.

Amasty\ImportCore\Console\Command\RunJob\Interceptor does not exist

We are in magento 2.4.3p1 with production mode.

Steps followed to do fix the issue but not helpful:

1. Removed var/ and generated/ folders.
2. Given the 777 permission issue to the var/ and generated/ folders.

Is that helpful, if we run the magento commands in developer mode? Please suggest.
[image]